# Port 25 blocked but Firewall is off

Tags: iptables, firewall, port, sendmail

OK so this is driving me crazy.

Running sendmail on CentOS.  It's running, and listening on 25:

```
[root@mysqlslavebackup ~]# nmap -sS -O -sV 127.0.0.1

Starting Nmap 4.11 ( http://www.insecure.org/nmap/ ) at 2013-03-21 10:46 PDD<br>
Interesting ports on localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1):<br>
Not shown: 1665 closed ports<br>
PORT      STATE SERVICE           VERSION<br>
22/tcp    open  ssh               OpenSSH 4.3 (protocol 2.0)<br>
25/tcp    open  smtp              Sendmail 8.13.8/8.13.8<br>
53/tcp    open  domain<br>
111/tcp   open  rpc<br>
631/tcp   open  ipp               CUPS 1.2<br>
739/tcp   open  rpc<br>
953/tcp   open  rndc?<br>
3306/tcp  open  mysql             MySQL 5.5.11-enterprise-commercial-advanced-log<br>
5901/tcp  open  vnc               VNC (protocol 3.8)<br>
5902/tcp  open  vnc               VNC (protocol 3.8)<br>
5903/tcp  open  vnc               VNC (protocol 3.8)<br>
6001/tcp  open  X11                (access denied)<br>
6002/tcp  open  X11                (access denied)<br>
6003/tcp  open  X11                (access denied)<br>
```

I can telnet to 25 from the localhost, but from any other machine it appears the port is closed.  iptables are off, and even if they were in I have an entry to open the port.

Can't for the life of me figure out what the heck it would be other than the fact this used to be a Zimbra mail server, but it has been uninstalled and there's no record of it in port bindings.

Any input would be awesome!  Thanks!

Comment: It could be blocked at the network firewall, or as answer posted by Michael suggests, Sendmail may not be listening on the public network interface.

Comment: Please post the output of `lsof -i -P | grep sendmail`. By default for CentOS sendmail only listens on localhost.

Comment: @MarkWagner `netstat -ant| grep :25` gives `tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN`

Comment: It is only listening on loopback. Andrzej's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Why can't I receive external mail/incoming SMTP connections?** [Sendmail and other MTA servers]

Are you *sure* your sendmail does not listen ONLY on loopback interface? [127.0.0.1:25]
It is default configuration on quite a few distributions.

You may use `netstat -ant| grep :25` to chek it.

Sendail FAQ 4.22: [Why can't I receive external mail?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/support/support_faq/general_issues_faq/#4.22)
In short: You may need to comment out DAEMON_OPTIONS line with 127.0.0.1 in your sendail.mc and recompile it into sendmail.cf.

Comment: To rebuild and recompile in CentOS, after you edit sendmail.mc you run /etc/mail/make followed by a service sendmail restart.